# OpenCV image is not showing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, gcc, opencv

I am working on the following code:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat im = imread("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Koala.jpg");
    if (im.empty())
    {
        cout << "Cannot load image!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    imshow("Image", im);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to test the OpenCV with QT, by simply opening an image. This is my very first QT application. However, the program runs, but there is no image display! The same code runs in VS 2010 and display the image correctly. Following is the only output I get from QT.

[image]

Following is my QT Project configuration.

**Tester.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-04-25T23:36:30
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = Tester
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\build\include\

LIBS += -LC:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib\
-lopencv_core240 \
-lopencv_highgui240 \
-lopencv_imgproc240 \
-lopencv_features2d240 \
-lopencv_calib3d240
```

Here are the version I am using:

- My OS - Windows 7 Ultimate
- QT Creator version - 2.7.0
- QT Downloaded from - http://qt-project.org/downloads (File Name is: qt-windows-opensource-5.0.2-mingw47_32-x86-offline)
- OpenCV Version - 2.4
- MinGW Version - Was installed sometime back in the 9th month of 2012. Don't know how to get the version number.

How can I make this opencv task work correctly?

### Update

I just checked the .exe file it built. It gives the following error when I double click on it

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use a path without white spaces in it?

Comment: I'd also try to put double slashes: C://Users//Public... this is how I'm used to do when the code should run on a Windows platform, single slashes didn't do the job for me.

Comment: @Subway: Thanks for the reply. I just attempted. No Good at all

Comment: @Subway: Anyway, "path" means image path right?

Comment: This path: C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Koala.jpg
So try to put the image in say C:/Users/Public/Pictures, and refer to it in the code as follows: C://Users//Public//Pictures//Koala.jpg

Answer (score 1):

That error means that the Operating System was unable to find the **.DLL** when your application was launched.

There are 2 ways to fix that:

- Locate and copy that **.DLL** to the **.exe** folder.
- Modify Windows' **PATH** *environment variable* and add the full path to that **.DLL**. It's best to reboot your machine after this change.